# Keyup function for editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to make application there i need  when input filed value enter than this value show in editable div.so i am using keyup function but now i need editable div value show in input filed i mean revers process.Below i am showing what i have done.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#input1').keyup(function () {
txt = $('#input1').val();
$('#field1').text(txt);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<div id="field1" contentEditable='true'; ></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the reverse. Here is the code:

```
$('#field1').keyup(function () {
$('#input1').val($('#field1').text());
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/yRzyE/1/